# CSS & HTML Margin

Tags: html, css

I'd like to move these two arrow images so it close to each other, at the moment I have them both quite apart. Here is what I need:

http://postimg.org/image/s4dv20xy1/

And here is my working progress: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GRpH/13/)

HTML:

```
<div id="arrow">
    <img src="http://gyazo.com/736c6c5e6e5e3355b804ccda9143560c.png" alt="Arrow1"></img>
    <img src="http://gyazo.com/736c6c5e6e5e3355b804ccda9143560c.png" alt="Arrow1"></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#arrow img {
            margin:2px;
}
```

Thanks.

PS: Ignore the left or right position

Comment: `#arrow img { float: left; }`. That`s all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use sibling selector:

```
#arrow img {
    margin: 2px;
}

#arrow img+img {
    margin-left: -25px;
}
```

working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GRpH/18/)

teorical info:

in css the `+` is an sibling combinator selector, it allows you to select an element that is directly after another specific element. in this example its a image that is next to an other image but you can use any elements for example you may want to aply an style to any paragraph that is next to a div, you  will use `div + p` and it will match any paragraph that is next to a div, in the other side if you want to match a element before another one, you shoud use the `-` sibling combinator in the example above it will match the `div` instead the `p`

Answer (score 0):

You can just set your margin to be negative (like `-10px`) and the arrows will get closer to each other.

Comment: Some notes on negative margins: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Comment: The arrows will not get closer together as the margin will be applied to all images!

Comment: The arrows will get closer together as its applied to "both" images. Using margin-right.

Comment: @GriffLab in which case you'd give them separate IDs, or you'd use one of the many CSS3 pseudo-classes

Comment: @DavidBlayney or use the proper css syntax provided by myself and Juan Antonio Orozco

Comment: @GriffLab My mistake, I didn't scroll down far enough on the page :P

Comment: Thanks all it seems to me all those solutions giving almost the same result but I was wondering what is the benefit ie giving them separate IDs instead of just using one ID but combine them as img+img as @Juan Antonio Orozco and using not first child selector as GriffLab explained?

Comment: Curious as the advantage in this use case as well. Always looking to code in a better way when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css not first child selector,

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/CarlG/Hhbtf/

Here is the css

```
#arrow img {
    margin:2px;
}

#arrow img:not(:first-child) {
    position: relative; right: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give both pictures a separate ID, you can move them both around individually. Like this:

HTML:

```
<img id="arrow1" src=""></img>
<img id="arrow2" src=""></img>
```

CSS:

```
#arrow2 {margin-left: -20px;}
#arrow1{margin-left: 0px;}
```

Comment: or you can use css siblings or not child selector

Comment: @Juan Antonio Orozco thanks but what is the advantages and better way to represent it?

Comment: the advantage is taht you dont need to put an id to each image and it would work with as mani images you put in the arrow div, lets say you want to put 3 arrows now, if you do it with id, you would need to add an id to the image, and make new css code for that arrow, in case you are using not first child or sibling selectors, you just need to add the image to the div, and for the way to represent it, it dont get it, you mean the code?

Answer (score -1):

I did it this way in the css using the same class:

```
#arrow img {
margin:2px;
padding:0px;
margin-right:-20px;
}
```

Working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/v6MPj/1/